# Can I test for an open stdin stream from within a bash script?

Tags: bash, io, stream

Assume I want to write all input to a script into a logfile, command line and standard in. So, if somebody pipes text to my script, I want to write that into the log as well, but if I'm invoked without input (e.g. from a login shell) the script will block if I try to `cat` or `read` standard in, waiting for the user to type something.

Can I somehow test for an open input stream? Or just capture all standard in, if and only if there is standard in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `-t` option on command `test`.

From the man:

> -t FD  file descriptor FD is opened on a terminal

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  echo "Pipe not open"
else
  echo "Pipe available"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to do what I'm looking for, although the output seems to be inverted to me.

Comment: No, actually you were correct the first time. I just thought the semantics of `test -t` were all backwards.